# Append text to the end of only first column in a file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
1,AB,DE
1,AB,DE
```

I want to append some text to the end of the first column ONLY, so it would look like the following:

```
1sometext,AB,DE
1sometext,AB,DE
```

I can use this code to append to the first column, but I'm not sure how to keep the rest of the line intact:

```
awk '{print $1"env1"}' file
```

Comment: You are almost there: awk -F, '{print $1"env1",$2,$3}' OFS=, file

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$1=$1"sometext"}1' inputfile
```

This will rewrite the first column with `$1` + `"sometext"` .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it with this syntax:

```
awk '{OFS = "\t";$1=$1"env1" ;print}' file
```

Comment: `awk -F"," '{OFS=","; $1=$1"env1"; print}' file` should do.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with

```
sed 's/^[^,]*/&sometext/' file
```

As @F.Hauri commented, this is overdone. Just do simple

```
sed 's/,/sometext,/' file
```

Comment: or `sed s/,/sometext,/`. Without `g` modifier, sed will work on 1st `,` only.